# Multiple images (xml -> javascript -> CSS) being overwritten, only 1 image being displayed

Tags: javascript, css, xml

I am building a simple scraping app that pulls data from an XML with format:

```
<entry>
  <title>Title of something</title>
  <summary>https://link_to_image_used_in_background</summary>
  <link>www.link-to-website.com</link>
</entry>
```

that is being read by javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadRSS('http://website.com/file.xml', '#Newsfeed', 'Heise');   
});

    function loadRSS(link, htmlContainer, author) {
        var url = link;
        var container = $(htmlContainer);
        feednami.load(url, function(result){
            if (result.error) {
                console.log(result.error);
            } else {
                var entries = result.feed.entries;
                for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++){
                    container.append("<li class=\"RSScard\"><p><h2>" 
                        + "<a href=\"" + entry.link + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + entry.title + '</a> ' 
                        + "</h2></p>"+ author +"</li>");

                var bg_url = entry.summary
                    $(function () {
                        $(".RSScard").css({
                            backgroundImage: "url('" + bg_url + "')"
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

and is passed to CSS:

```
body {
  background: #444;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#Newsfeed {
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 65px;
}

.RSScard {
    padding: 20px 25px;

    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;

    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-height: 225px;

    opacity: .87;
    background-image: var(plink);;

  color: #388E3C;
  font-size: 0.85em;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0, 0.25);
    float:left;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.RSScard a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ededed;
  font-size: 0.75em;
    font-weight: 300;
    opacity: 1;
}

.RSScard:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #202B33;
}
```

.... my problem is that it that while the title and link are written to their respective space correctly, each space's background image is overwritten by the last xml entry's 'summary' child. My apologies for the probably poor coding and formatting - I initially took Tobias Totz's rss reader / feeder (https://codepen.io/tobias-totz/pen/rrJXqo) and tried to hotwire it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In your XML i cant see information related to background, not sure what you want to achieve? Card background should be set based on what information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are setting the background image to all elements with class *RSScard* in every iteration of the loop. That's why you are able to see only the last item image because you have overridden the previous ones.

You would need to do something like the following to set a different image for each enty:

```
for(var entry in entries){
  var $listElement = $("<li class=\"RSScard\".... </li>");

  container.append($listElement);

  $listElement.css({
      backgroundImage: "url('" + entry.summary + "')"
  });   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.. i see the problem, especially now that you've given me a push in the right direction. But for the life of me I cannot get it to work. Idk if its syntax issues or logical errors but I either get repeating images or undefined blocks with no background images

Comment: Actually I think i have the main problem solved now. The images will show up but only if they are preloaded.. another obstacle!